# ansible json_query to extract value dependant on other field

Tags: json, ansible, json-query

Looking to extract href value for each flavor from below json when rel==self and I just can't work it out

```
{
    "flavors": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "links": [
                {
                    "href": "http://127.0.0.1:8764/v2.1/flavors/1",
                    "rel": "self"
                },
                {
                    "href": "http://127.0.0.1:8764/flavors/1",
                    "rel": "bookmark"
                }
            ],
            "name": "m1.tiny"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "links": [
                {
                    "href": "http://127.0.0.1:8764/v2.1/flavors/2",
                    "rel": "self"
                },
                {
                    "href": "http://127.0.0.1:8764/flavors/2",
                    "rel": "bookmark"
                }
            ],
            "name": "m1.small"
        },
        {
            "id": "3",
            "links": [
                {
                    "href": "http://127.0.0.1:8764/v2.1/flavors/3",
                    "rel": "self"
                },
                {
                    "href": "http://127.0.0.1:8764/flavors/3",
                    "rel": "bookmark"
                }
            ],
            "name": "m1.medium"
        }                              
    ]
}
```

I have tried below but just cant get the `jmesquery: 'flavors.links[?contains(rel,` self`)]'` query to work?

```
 - name: 
     uri:
       url: 'http://192.168.1.182:8774/v2.1/flavors'
       method: GET
       body_format: json
       headers:
         X-Auth-Token: "{{ ansible_facts.auth_token }}"
         Content-Type: "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
       return_content: yes
     register: this

  - debug:
        msg: "{{ this }}"

  - name: save the Json data to a Variable as a Fact
    set_fact:
      jsondata: "{{ this }}"

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ jsondata }}"

  - name: save the Json data to a Variable as a Fact
    set_fact:
      flavors: "{{ jsondata | json_query(jmesquery) }}"
    vars:
      jmesquery: 'json.flavors'

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ flavors }}"

  - name: LINKS
    set_fact:
      links: "{{ jsondata | json_query(jmesquery) }}"
    vars:
      jmesquery: 'flavors.links[?contains(rel, `self`)]'

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ links }}"
```

I can print the values for all href using below...

```
 - name: save the Json data to a Variable as a Fact
   set_fact:
     href: "{{ jsondata | json_query(jmesquery) }}"
   vars:
   jmesquery: 'json.flavors[*].links[].href'

 - debug:
     msg: "{{ href }}"
```

Any help appreciated?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I have eventually worked it out...

```
- name: save the Json data to a Variable as a Fact
  set_fact:
    href: "{{ jsondata | json_query(jmesquery) }}"
  vars:
    jmesquery: json.flavors[].links[?rel==`self`].href

- debug:
    msg: "{{ href }}"
```